# Inserting a ❤ symbol into text

Tags: text-object

I'm trying to put a piece of text into Blender 2.76, most of it works and is OK, putting the ❤ symbol into the text editor pane works. When I try and put it into a text object, all I get is a square symbol (i.e. can't display it).  I've tried copy and pasting the char in (even the Insert Text pane entry field), tried changing the font and run out of ideas.

Is there a specific font I should use?  Or is there something else I'm missing?

**Update:**
Finally managed to get something I was after, here's a render of it so far...
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're on Windows try selecting the font "MS Mincho" (it should be  `C:\Windows\Fonts\MSMINCHO.TTF`). Or MS Gothic (`msgothic.ttc`), this is how Libreoffice Writer gets it.

At least that font is used on my Microsoft Word (on Windows 7) when I paste your char into a blank document. I tried setting both the above on Blender, and it works:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I'm running on Ubuntu, but managed to download this font and it gives me the same as your getting :)

Comment: see updated post, also MS gothic seems to work... maybe others.

Comment: It displayed as a heart in most fonts in LibreOffice, but it didn't seem to translate to Blender.  Just need to work out how to set this font programmatically when I create a new text object.

Comment: yes, LO always displays it, even with "arial" or "liberation serif"... the weird thing is that neither ms gothic or ms mincho have this heart in their character set... some obscure font wizardry, I suspect.

Comment: Managed to find `fnt = bpy.data.fonts.load(...)`, so on to the next problem!  Thanks for your help.